# How to add vertical lines to StackPane with JavaFx

Tags: javafx, line

I'm creating interactive gant chart based on JavaFx nodes. 
Pictures shows me concept.

```
1. Operations are placed inside of VBox
2. VBox is placed inside of StackPane and then inside of ScrollPane.
3. I have vertical time lines responsible for hours.
```

This is the method which im using for adding vertical timelines:

```
//sp is my StackPane
//line every 60 px / minutes

for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
   lines[i] = new Line(i * 60, 0, i * 60, sp.getWidth());
   sp.getChildren().add(lines[i]);
}
```

Problem is that all the lines are added one by one in the middle of Gant Chart. Basicly I think the problem is that Java is not correctly setting X (start, end) , Y (start, end ) values ....

any advice?

[image: Gant chart nodes schema]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Why StackPane does not work*

StackPane is a layout pane, it positions it's content according to constraints on the content such as the [alignment constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html#setAlignment%28javafx.geometry.Pos%29).  The default alignment for a StackPane is to center everything in the Stack.  Layout panes will generally ignore any manual settings you provide to layout content inside them (as they manage the layout themselves).

*Solution: Use a Group or Pane*

What you want to do is use a container other than a StackPane which does not automatically layout the content positions.  Examples of containers you could use are a [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) or a [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html).

*You can wrap your new parent in a StackPane*

You can always wrap your parent container in a StackPane if you want it centered in it's available layout area (which is generally the way that a StackPane is used).